# Grouping the same fields of rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, grouping

I need to grouping employee names together. I tried to use "Order By" but it didn't work for empty cells.

[image]

The table at the top is my current table and I want the result like the table at the bottom. Here is my current select query.

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(calendar.DATE) AS DAY,
    DATE_FORMAT(calendar.DATE, '%d %b %Y') AS Date,
    t2.Department,
    t2.Name,
    TIME(t2.time_enter) AS 'Time In',
    TIME(t2.time_exit) AS 'Time Out'
FROM
    calendar
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        employee_hr_id,
            time_enter,
            time_exit,
            department.NAME As Department,
            CONCAT(employee.F_NAME, ' ', employee.L_NAME) As Name
    from
        entry_log
    Inner Join employee ON entry_log.EMPLOYEE_HR_ID = employee.HR_ID
    Inner Join department ON employee.DEPARTMENT_ID = department.ID
    where
        CONCAT(employee.F_NAME, ' ', employee.L_NAME) LIKE @NAME) t2 ON date(t2.time_enter) = calendar.date
where
    calendar.DATE >= @TIME_ENTER
        AND calendar.DATE <= @TIME_EXIT
```

Comment: What about using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN in the first joining?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but if I use INNER JOIN, empty rows like Saturday or Sunday won't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just CALENDAR table you should use following subquery.

```
select calendar.DATE,employee.HR_ID,employee.DEPARTMENT_ID 
  from calendar,employee 
  where
    calendar.DATE >= @TIME_ENTER
        AND calendar.DATE <= @TIME_EXIT
```

In this case you get all possible combinations of DATE and EMPLOYEE. And then order by `DEPARTMENT_ID, HR_ID, DATE` from this table.

So your query should looks like:

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(NEW_calendar.DATE) AS DAY,
    DATE_FORMAT(NEW_calendar.DATE, '%d %b %Y') AS Date,
    t2.Department,
    t2.Name,
    TIME(t2.time_enter) AS 'Time In',
    TIME(t2.time_exit) AS 'Time Out'
FROM
    (
       select calendar.DATE as DATE,
              employee.HR_ID as HR_ID,
              employee.DEPARTMENT_ID as DEPARTMENT_ID
            from calendar,employee 
            where
              calendar.DATE >= @TIME_ENTER
                AND calendar.DATE <= @TIME_EXIT
     ) NEW_calendar
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        employee_hr_id,
            time_enter,
            time_exit,
            department.NAME As Department,
            CONCAT(employee.F_NAME, ' ', employee.L_NAME) As Name
    from
        entry_log
    Inner Join employee ON entry_log.EMPLOYEE_HR_ID = employee.HR_ID
    Inner Join department ON employee.DEPARTMENT_ID = department.ID
    where
        CONCAT(employee.F_NAME, ' ', employee.L_NAME) LIKE @NAME) t2 

        ON date(t2.time_enter) = NEW_calendar.date
           and (t2.EMPLOYEE_HR_ID=NEW_calendar.HR_ID)
where
    calendar.DATE >= @TIME_ENTER
        AND calendar.DATE <= @TIME_EXIT

order by NEW_calendar.DEPARTMENT_ID,NEW_calendar.HR_ID,NEW_calendar.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the empty rows to indicate what employee you'd associate with them. In fact they should not even be duplicate at all. The way to go is to join three tables (or subqueries): one for the dates, the second for *all* (relevant) employees, the third with the actual assignments. Then you can use the second table of all employees to order rows, even if you choose not to print the names. The full cross join between the first two tables gives you *all* combinations between dates and employees, and the ones with log entries can then be left joined to that.

I've created [an example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f249/4). It uses employee Names instead of IDs to match things, and takes `t2` as a table instead of a more complicated subquery, but the idea should be clean nonetheless. Here is the query from that fiddle:

```
SELECT …
FROM
    (calendar,
     (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM t2) AS employees)
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON DATE(t2.time_enter) = calendar.date
                AND t2.Name = employees.Name
ORDER BY employees.Name, calendar.date
```

Comment: Thank you for the introducing me SQLFiddle.